# warning: passing argument 1 of ‘calculation’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]

Tags: c, arrays

I keep getting this error and I can't find the problem:

```
exam.c: In function ‘main’:
exam.c:21:2: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘calculation’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
exam.c:2:5: note: expected ‘int *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
exam.c:21:2: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘calculation’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
exam.c:2:5: note: expected ‘int *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
```

I tried to change the arrays to pointers, but that did not work either. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int calculation(int arrayOne[50], int arrayTwo[50], int i);
int main(void) {

        int myArray[50];
        int myArrayTwo[50];
        int i;

        for(i=0;i<49;i++) {

                printf("Enter values of arrays: ");
                scanf("%d", &myArray[i]);
                printf("Enter second value: ");
                scanf("%d", &myArrayTwo[i]);
                if (myArray[i] == 0) {

                        break;
                }
        }

        calculation(myArray[i], myArrayTwo[i], i);
}

int calculation(int arrayOne[50], int arrayTwo[50], int i) {

        int total;
        int j;

        for (j=0;j<i;j++) {

                total = arrayOne[j] + arrayTwo[j];
        }
}
```

What I am trying to do is create a program which can hold 50 different values and if a user enters 0 for myArray then the program ends. 
The program passes the values to calculation function and calculation functions calculates the arrays and show the total value.

Comment: `arrayOne` and `arrayTwo` are expecting a pointer to `int`, but you are passing a plain `int`

Comment: Read the error again, and think about that the expressions `myArray[i]` and `myArrayTwo[i]` are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send `array` as function parameters, you have to send the base address of the `array` and receive it with a `pointer to the same type`. Something like

You are receiving it as a pointer, but you are sending `int` instead of the base address of the array,

```
calculation(myArray[i], myArrayTwo[i], i);
            ^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                  int not int*
```

---

For an array `myArray[50]` its name `myArray` represents the base address of the array, so you can use something like this

```
calculation(myArray, myArrayTwo, i); //myArray is the base address of myArray[] array
.
.
int calculation(int* arrayOne, int* arrayTwo, int i)
//OR
int calculation(int arrayOne[], int arrayTwo[], int i)
//OR
int calculation(int arrayOne[50], int arrayTwo[50], int i)
```